Elements are not displayed after page redirection in automated tests in WebdriverIO
I have flaky tests, with tests sometimes passing and failing. Main cause I found is the only time when redirected to that certain page the elements cannot be displayed, existed, clicked etc. Tried to increase timeouts but still no help. Most efficient elements were taken either with CSS selector or XPATH and checked using developer tools console. Can anyone help what may be the reason and what could help, please?
My test file vpsHostingPlan.test.js:
describe('The VPS Hosting plan should be displayed, term option should be changed and total cost should be calculated', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await homePage.openPage();
    await vpsPage.selectVPS4vCPU();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await cookiesHelper.deleteCookies();
    await browser.refresh();
    await browser.execute(() => {
      sessionStorage.clear();
    });
  });

  it('The total cost of all added plans should be calculated correctly', async () => {
    const totalCost = await orderServerPlan.getTotalCost();
    const totalPlanSummaryPrice = await orderServerPlan.getSummaryPrice();
    const roundedTotalCost = Math.round(totalCost * 100) / 100;
    const roundedSummaryPrice = Math.round(totalPlanSummaryPrice * 100) / 100;
    expect(roundedTotalCost).toBe(roundedSummaryPrice);
  });

Methods which I call from spec test files
async getTotalCost() {
    await $('.sec-header').waitForExist({ timeout: 30000 });
    await waiters.waitForElementToBeDisplayed(this.vps4vcpTotalPrice, 40000);
    await this.vps4vcpTotalPrice.scrollIntoView();
    const sidebarTotalText = await this.vps4vcpTotalPrice.getText();
    const totalMatch = sidebarTotalText.match(/Total:\s*\$\s*([0-9.,]+)/);
    return parseFloat(totalMatch[1].replace(/,/g, ''));
  }

async selectVPS4vCPU() {
    await this.click(this.vpsHostingLink);
    await this.vps4vcpuBtn.scrollIntoView();
    await waiters.waitForElementToBeDisplayed(this.vps4vcpuBtn);
    await this.vps4vcpuBtn.waitForDisplayed();
    await this.click(this.vps4vcpuBtn);
    await waiters.waitForLoaderToComplete(loader.pageLoader, 30000);
 }

My waiter methods in helper folder
class Waiters {
  DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 10000;
  async waitForLoaderToComplete(loaderElement, timeout = this.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) {
    await browser.waitUntil(async () => !(await loaderElement.isDisplayed()), {
      timeout,
      timeoutMsg: `Loader did not complete within ${timeout}ms`,
    });
  }

  async waitForElementToBeDisplayed(element, timeout = this.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) {
    await browser.waitUntil(
      async () => await element.isDisplayed(),
      { timeout, timeoutMsg: `Element ${await element.selector} was not displayed within ${timeout}ms` }
    );
  }

  async waitForPageLoad(timeout = this.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) {
    await browser.waitUntil(
      async () => browser.execute(() => document.readyState === 'complete'),
      {
        timeout: timeout,
        timeoutMsg: `Page did not finish loading within ${timeout} ms`,
      },
    );
  }

  async waitForClickable(element, timeout = this.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) {
    await browser.waitUntil(async () => await element.isClickable(), {
      timeout: timeout,
      timeoutMsg: `Element ${await element.selector} was not clickable within ${timeout}ms`,
    });
  }

  async waitForUrlToBe(expectedUrl, timeout = this.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) {
    await browser.waitUntil(async () => {
      const currentUrl = await browser.getUrl();
      return currentUrl === expectedUrl;
    }, {
      timeout,
      timeoutMsg: `Expected URL to be "${expectedUrl}" but got "${await browser.getUrl()}" after ${timeout}ms`
    });
  }
}

module.exports = new Waiters();

I need to find a way to get the elements all the time and have passing tests.

In my experience, test are flaky when you start testing without being certain if the elements that are tested are already on the page.
That can be because of the page load being slow at the time of testing, or because of element being loaded with ajax.
For example, in your case the first interactions are done by selectVPS4vCPU(), but without checking if the page is loaded (await this.click(this.vpsHostingLink);, scrollintoview). By doing so the page is frozen in the state of the start of the first await. Sometimes the page is loaded already, sometimes not => flaky.
When not sure if the page is loaded (which is the case here), you should START with a waiting operation to check if no data is being loaded. For example by waiting for an expected element to appear, or by waiting for a loader icon to disappear. And certainly not by waiting a fixed period of time.

Yes, but where? Could show with an example in code pls because I have this waiter method for a page loader to disappear but it didn't help? I'm pretty newbie here and your help would help me a lot and appreciated! @ruud

the fist thing you do is calling selectVPS4vCPU and you start right away with a click. If you precede the click by a call to a proper wait, then you avoid problems at that point. The main thing is that you have to look for yourself exactly where the current problem is (the flakiness) and wait there for the content to be loaded. We have not enought information to pinpoint this. Maybe you can analyse the log or the manual runs...
